# setw() length of string is larger than configured limit

Tags: c++, setw

I am planning to organize output strings in double column in terminal console, where `setw()` is applied to configure the widths of each columns.

I nonetheless find if length of the string, which is to be displayed in the right column, exceeds the pre-configured limit, the residual part will be put on the beginning of the next line. But I want it still at right part.

For example,

```
std::string a = "Hello World";
std::string b = "Stack Overflow is awesome";
std::cout << std::setw(140) << left << a
          << std::setw(5) << left << b << std::endl;
```

"Overflow" will be in the left column but I want it to be in right. Output will be:

`Hello World                                                                  S
tack Overflow`

Is there any solution to it? Or I have to write a print function customizing this condition?

Comment: IME you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess so...

Comment: Can you quote the actual output in your post?

Comment: The output you're seeing depends on the size of the console you're on. When I'm on my terminal the residual part that appears on the next line is `"esome"`. If you're okay with it just working for consoles with your size ratio, you can implement a custom print function yourself.